# Copying Tensorflow - __enter__ and __exit__ errors using context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I tried to use with numpy.load('file.npy') as bar but it gives me an error of attributeError: _enter__ and at a different time attributeError: _exit__. I was just trying to copy what the example shown on Tensorflow's page did. I don't understand why their code would work but mine -which should be the same- wouldn't.

[image: my attempt]

[image: Tensorflow pic]

Comment: The Tensorflow example works because it's actually loading a `npz` archive (despite the name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [29]: f = open('con.npy')
In [30]: f.__enter__
Out[30]: <function TextIOWrapper.__enter__>
In [31]: f.__exit__
Out[31]: <function TextIOWrapper.__exit__>
In [32]: f.close()
In [33]: arr = np.load('con.npy')
```

`arr` is a `ndarray` and does not have `__enter__` method.

A `npz` file is a zip archive, and does have a `__enter__`.  It should useable in a `with`:

```
In [34]: ls *.npz
Mcoo.npz  Mcsr.npz  test.npz
In [35]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [36]: d.__enter__
Out[36]: <bound method NpzFile.__enter__ of <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x7fc5e03f7cf8>>
```

SO using the `npz` in a with:

```
In [39]: with np.load('test.npz') as d:
    ...:     print(list(d.keys()))
    ...:     a = d['a']
    ...:     
['a', 'b']
In [40]: a
Out[40]: array(1)
```

Usually we don't bother using the `with` for a `npz`, because there's no cost (that I know of) of hanging on to the dictionary like object.

---

In the Tensorflow example, `features = data['features']` is consistent with `data` being an opened `NPZ` archive.  So despite the `npy`, this `load` is an archive.  The distinction is based on data bits in the file itself (a `_ZIP_PREFIX`), not the filename.

From the `load` documentation:

```
- If the file is a ``.npz`` file, the returned value supports the
  context manager protocol in a similar fashion to the open function::

    with load('foo.npz') as data:
        a = data['a']
```

Comment: _"because there's no cost (that I know of) of hanging on to the dictionary like object."_ - well, except that this dictionary-like object holds onto a file, so [now you're leaving the file open too](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b47ed76ebfbbd91b5d475eb19043a98e95dc2ad5/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L212-L223)

Comment: @Eric, I wrote that bit before seeing the context documentation.